# Csv data from Papa parse to React / useState to Node to MongoDB Atlas. insertMany

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, csv, mongoose

I implemented papa parse in React for the user to be able to upload the contents of a csv file into MongoDB (Atlas). Papa parse converts the Csv (with mulitple entries) into a json file which is then stored into a useState in React. Now I am trying to get this json data into MongoDB using Node/Express. It works flawlessly posting with Postman but not with React. So I guess it should be some mistake in the userFunctions.js or CSVReader.js file. Any help will be much appreciated!

```
// userFunctions.js

export const dataUpload = data => {

    return axios.post('http://localhost:3002/event/create', {

                seriennummer : data.seriennummer,
                bezeichnung : data.bezeichnung,
                verkaufspreis : data.verkaufspreis,
                besonderheiten : data.besonderheiten,
                
    })
    .then(res => console.log('event created'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

```
// CSVReader.js

const CSVReader = () => {
  const [parsedCsvData, setParsedCsvData] = useState();
  

  const parseFile = (file) => {
    Papa.parse(file, {
      header: true,
      complete: (results) => {
        setParsedCsvData(results.data);
      },
     
    });
  };

  console.log(parsedCsvData);

  const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles) => {
    if (acceptedFiles.length) {
      parseFile(acceptedFiles[0]);
    }
  }, []);

  const {
    getRootProps,
    getInputProps,
    isDragActive,
    isDragAccept,
    isDragReject,
  } = useDropzone({
    onDrop,
    accept: "text/csv",
  });

  const createEvent = (e) => {

    const newEvent = {
     
                seriennummer : parsedCsvData,
                 bezeichnung : parsedCsvData,
                verkaufspreis : parsedCsvData,
                besonderheiten : parsedCsvData,
                
    }
    dataUpload(newEvent)

  }

  return (
    <div>
      <GlobalStyles />

      <section
        className="jumbotron breadcumb no-bg"
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${"./img/background/subheader.jpg"})` }}
      >
        <div className="mainbreadcumb">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row m-10-hor">
              <div className="col-12">
                <h1 className="text-center">CSV Datei hochladen - Uhren</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-7 offset-lg-1 mb-5"></div>
          <div
            {...getRootProps({
              className: `dropzone 
          ${isDragAccept && "dropzoneAccept"} 
          ${isDragReject && "dropzoneReject"}`,
            })}
          >
            <input {...getInputProps()} />
            {isDragActive ? (
              <p>Drop the files here ...</p>
            ) : (
              <h3>
                <p>
               Drag and Drop CSV File Here
                </p>
              </h3>
            )}
          </div>
          <div>
          <button type="submit" onClick={createEvent} class="form-control btn btnSign submit fs-3 ">CREATE NOW</button>
            <div className="spacer-10"></div>
            <div className="spacer-10"></div>
            <table className="lead">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Seriennummer</th>
                  <th>Firma</th>
                  <th>Preis</th>
                  <th>Besonderheiten</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {parsedCsvData &&
                  parsedCsvData.map((parsedData, index) => (
                    <tr key={index}>
                      <td>{parsedData.seriennummer}</td>
                      <td>{parsedData.bezeichnung}</td>
                      <td>{parsedData.verkaufspreis}</td>
                      <td>{parsedData.besonderheiten}</td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CSVReader;
```

```
// Controller

const createEvent = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const event = await Event.insertMany(req.body)
        res.json({
        msg: "Created Event",
        success: true,
        data: event,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.json({
        success: false,
        data: err,
        });
    }
};
```

![console.log of the useState parsedCsvData][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5jZg.png

![Nodejs console][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPNXP.png

Answer (score 0):

based on [this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPNXP.png), I believe `req.body` is stringified JSON. You need to do `const data = JSON.parse(req.body)` or use [body-parser with express](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html)